# Get objects who have a field that contains a string

Tags: python

I have a list of objects and I want to only return objects that have a field that contains a certain value.

Is there a more terse/pythonic way of doing this:

```
list-o-dicts = get-my-objects()

for dict in list-o-dicts:
    if 'mystring' in dict['myfield']:
        pprint( dict )
```

Does python have a cool, sugary, shortcut for doing this?

Comment: I suppose you could use a list comprehension if you wanted to sugar it up for no good reason: `output = [dict for dict in list-o-dicts if 'mystring' in dict['myfield']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filter(lambda x: 'mystring' in x['myfield'], list-o-dicts)
```